# redirect http to https AWS LB configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

Here is my nginx configuration

```
 server {
        listen       80;
     location / {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            rewrite ^ https://test.com$request_uri?;
        } 
    }
}

server {
        listen       443;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/key.crt;
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    client_max_body_size 300M;

      location / {
            root   /var/www/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

}
```

I configured both http and https to instance port 80 and the certificate.
when I try to hit the website the redirect works fine but it takes me to nginx landing page, it does not seem to read the config on 443.

Comment: This line: `listen localhost:443;` looks out of place. I think you need to remove that and only have the one `listen 443;` line.

Comment: It is a double entry, did not matter, still having same issue.